# create many singleton objects of one object for gridPane in java

Tags: java, javafx, singleton, gridpane

I have a gridPane with three columns(name, counter, timeStamp pos). 
For the column timeStamp pos I have an object where I can jump to a position or move to the next/previous position with the keyboard.
Every timeStamp pos cell is an object.
I have refactored some other components to singleton so when i open a view I only create them once and reuse them the next time I need them.
This is mainly to improve the performance of the application.
Is it possible to build x amount of singleton (or something similar to singleton that would do the job) objects for my grid?
This would help me a lot since I have about 25 rows which would be built every time i open the view.

Comment: This isn't a singleton you're trying to implement any more. Singletons are a way to ensure a single instance of a object exists in a application and this instance can be accessed from everywhere. Both are things you do not want in your case. Simply store the objects in a suitable data structure. A `List` would work fine for most use cases...

Comment: "x amount of singleton" is wrong for all x not equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to build x amount of singleton (or something similar to
>   singleton that would do the job) objects for my grid?

Yes, as long as x=1. [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is a design pattern that "restricts the instantiation of a class to one object".  In other words, when you correctly create a singleton of class A, then you will have a single, shared A-object instance available at run time.

Rather than using a singleton, I would simply implement a class that represents one row of data that you want to display. If there are 3 columns on your grid, then your class would have 3 member variables. Then, the task would simply be to retrieve any data you wish to display, and for each record, create a new "row" object, populate it, and then add it to a collection.  In the grid, simply iterate through the collection and display the current row data.